# Bluetooth mouse not pairing in 20.04 and 20.10

Tags: 20.04, mouse, bluetooth, 20.10

I have been running Ubuntu Mate 18.04 on a Lenovo Yoga 920-13IKB. I want to try out Ubuntu Desktop 20.10. I downloaded the ISO and built a USB boot drive; it boots into a desktop successfully. When I try to pair my Bluetooth mouse by bringing up Bluetooth Settings and turning on Bluetooth, it says it's searching for devices. When I then press the pairing button on the mouse, the mouse shows up in the Settings display marked as "Not set up". If I click on the entry for the mouse, "Not set up" changes to the Busy icon for a while, then the mouse disappears from the display and it goes back to searching for devices. From what I can gather using bluetoothctl it looks like the mouse has been recognized as a pointing device, but I may be reading too much into its output, and bluetoothctl is no more able to pair with the mouse than the graphical interface was.

Anyone have any thoughts on ways to get around this or what I should look at? At the moment I'm stuck - I don't have a spare hub, and the laptop only has one type A USB port, so the Bluetooth mouse is my only available option for testing with the USB boot drive. I use the same mouse with 18.04 on that laptop with no issues.

I have tried the same test on 20.4.1. It fails rather more immediately: When the mouse identifies itself to the laptop an entry for the mouse flashes up in the Bluetooth Settings display. It lasts for only a fraction of a second before it disappears and the interface goes back to searching for devices. In bluetoothctl there is no discernable delay between the message announcing the mouse as a new device and the subsequent message announcing that the device has been deleted. There doesn't seem to be anything related in dmesg or syslog.

Output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A3

```
6b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Lenovo QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:0827]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
6c:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM961/PM961 [144d:a804]
```

Output of lsusb

```
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 154b:00ed PNY USB 3.0 FD
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0626 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB3.1 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0cf3:e300 Qualcomm Atheros Communications QCA61x4 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 067b:2517 Prolific Technology, Inc. Flash Disk Mass Storage Device
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 067b:2515 Prolific Technology, Inc. Flash Disk Embedded Hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 06cb:0081 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 5986:210d Acer, Inc EasyCamera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of dmesg | grep -i blue

```
[   22.554460] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   22.554479] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   22.554482] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   22.554483] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   22.554485] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   22.691324] Bluetooth: hci0: using rampatch file: qca/rampatch_usb_00000302.bin
[   22.691326] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA: patch rome 0x302 build 0x3e8, firmware rome 0x302 build 0x111
[   22.755716] Bluetooth: hci0: using NVM file: qca/nvm_usb_00000302.bin
[   27.129404] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   27.129405] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   27.129409] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   98.809929] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   98.809934] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   98.809937] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Then please add output of `dmesg | grep -i blue`.

Answer (score 0):

This question is now o.b.e. I was investigating 20.04 and 20.10 because I had upgraded the Ubuntu Mate 18.04 installation on this laptop to 20.10 and it appeared that I wasn't going to be able to use the most recent version of Mate anymore. Today I tried booting into the installed Ubuntu Mate 20.10 and ran the Software Updater. Among other things it updated all the Bluetooth-related software. Upon rebooting with a fully updated Ubuntu Mate 20.10 I was able to use the Bluetooth mouse with no problems.

In the process of this investigation I discovered that I had failed to install one required package that was preventing my normal workflow from working on 20.10, and with that corrected it looks like I can stay with Mate for a while.

I don't have the resources to test it, but it seems likely that if this problem is fixed in Ubuntu Mate 20.10, it is fixed in all flavors of Ubuntu 20.10.